# create a safe placeholder in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a helper function that is called by a templating library.   My helper generates at the moment a div with a guid id - which is used as a placeholder - as well as a script which calls back to the server every second to get content to put into that placeholder - with essentially this code:

```
$.get( url + guid).done( result => $("#" +guid).html( result));
```

so - it all works perfectly - *unless* my helper function is used inside a table block - in which case, because `<div>` is not an allowed child of tbody - chrome kicks it out... so when I actually turn up with rows and columns later - they are no longer inside the table block - they turn up above it.

Now, of course the problem is that you get no context in the template renderer - ie it's completely impossible for me to know whether or not I'm in a table.

Can anyone think of any way I can put any sort of placeholder - text, comment, whatever inside my initial rendered html in a way that I can update it multiple times and the new html I insert will always appear exactly in the same place and context the original template instruction was?

Comment: Well then don’t use a div, but a tr or a td element …? With so little information, rather unclear what you are actually asking, resp. what the true problem is. Please show proper examples.

Comment: my helper function is being used in a template - eg {{#myfunc}} ...html ... {{/myfunc}}  - so I have no idea what's below it or whats above it.  tbody/tr is just one example of where it doesn't work - but if I used tr, then it wouldn't work if the helper function was used inside a tr for instance.  I need to find something, and I'm guessing the only option is going to be a comment, that I can use javascript to easily replace with html, can be _anywhere_ in the document, and the browser won't re-position it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found *an* answer - I'd still like a better one, but if I use comments like <!-- start --> and <!-- stop --> I can replace them with this:

```js
var inner = document.body.innerHTML;
var comment = s => "<!-- " + s + " -->";
var reg = new RegExp( comment("start") + "(.|\n)*" + comment("stop"), "gim");
var replaced = inner.replace( reg, comment("start") + "<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>" 
                          + comment("stop"));
document.body.innerHTML = replaced;
```

being careful to construct the regexp so that it doesn't match itself :)   Anyway - not ideal replacing the entire innerhtml - but it's my answer unless anyone can come up with something better.  Because comments *don't* get moved - from anywhere.

Comment: With that you got to be careful though, that your comments do not get removed - by a minifier/cache plugin for example, or even by the ISP (mobile traffic.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `<span></span>` element.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp)'s a pretty straightforward explanation:

> The  tag is used to group inline-elements in a document.
>
> The  tag provides no visual change by itself.
>
> The  tag provides a way to add a hook to a part of a text or a
>   part of a document.

Comment: thanks for the idea - but just tried it - if you put table/tbody/span - the browser repositions the span out of the table, moving it to before the table :(

Comment: And using a <p> element?

Comment: Haven’t tried - but the docs say that the only element allowed inside a Tbody is a tr

Comment: I've seen projects with really 'hacky' solutions due to limitions from the framework - including div-, button- and even script tags inside td elements. An ugly solution, but worked fine cross-browser